# Sort MySQL strings based on keywords using data mining technique

Tags: mysql, data-mining, string-matching

I have MySQL database where I'm storing N strings.Now I want to group them based on predefined keywords.I'm not supposed to use MySQL opeartions sucs as GROUPBY etc.Is there any technique in data mining to achieve the same?

Comment: Why are you not "supposed to" use the built-in means for this?

Comment: I'm doing android project on public portal.So i want to eliminate duplicates and group them under single category.According to college rules direct database operations are not allowed.We have to use data mining techniques only

Comment: What a pity, because SQL seems to be the right tool for this, not data mining... and you can't do data mining in MySQL, but that is where your data is...